# Linked lists | Overloading + operator | C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm training my C++ and I'm trying to write a library that'll be able to represent the following number using linked lists:

**999999999 * ( [i=0]Σ[999999999] 1000000000 ^ i )**

For example if my number was **711381450277869054011**, it'll be represented like this:

**711** * 1000000000^**2** + **381450277** * 1000000000^**1** + **869054011** * 1000000000^**0**

So, here is the struct of my LL and it's functions:

```
typedef struct node* ll;
struct node
{
    unsigned int data;
    ll next;
};

bool insert(ll&, unsigned int);
// ...
void copy(ll&, ll);
void destroy(ll&);
```

And here is my class of unsigned very long integers:

```
class uli
{
public:
    uli();
    ~uli();

    // <<, >>, =, operators...

    uli& operator +=(const uli&);
    uli& operator +=(char*);
    const uli operator +(const uli&);

private:
    ll head;
};

uli::uli()
{
    head = NULL;

    insert(head, 0);
}

uli::~uli()
{
    destroy(head);
}
```

**+=** operator works fine and I'm using it to overload the **+** operator.

The problem is that I can't make the method **operator+()** return a **const uli** without it being destroyed by the deconstructor before I get to use it.

```
const uli uli::operator +(const uli& rarg) // rarg: right argument
{
    uli larg; // left argument

    larg = *this;

    larg += rarg;

    return larg;
}
// returns an LL to somewhere ???? larg was destroyed.
```

Now I can't do `Z = X + Y;`

Comment: Have you implemented the copy constructor?

Comment: no I didn't. is that critical?

Comment: @jonas: Yes. If you don't create one, then the compiler has to, since that's how returning from a function works. And the compiler's version just copies the contents of the object -- including the `head` pointer -- rather than doing any sort of deep copy.

Comment: I see. Is that why it can't temporary hold the returned uli?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to follow the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**,

> If your class needs either
>
> - a copy constructor,
> - an assignment operator,
> - or a destructor,
>
> then it is likely to need all three of them.

**Root Cause of your problems:**
In your case When you return a class `uli` instance by copy from overloaded `operator +` the compiler generated implicit copy constructor is used and it makes a shallow copy of your pointers, thus multiple pointers point to the same memory address and when one/some of them(temporary objects) gets destroyed the pointed to memory is deallocated through the destructor and that leaves others pointers (dangling)pointing to memory/content that does not exist.

**Solution:**
Follow the Rule of Three and implement your own copy constructor to perform **[Deep Copying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy)** of the involved pointers.